# Return the element of a list which fulfills a certain condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
class Point
{
    double X, Y;
}
```

From a `List<Point>`, say I want the `Point` where `Point.X + Point.Y` is maximum in the list. How would I do this in LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be one way (though not optimal by any means):

```
List<Point> list = ...;
Point maxPoint = list.OrderByDescending(p => p.X + p.Y).First();
```

Another way which should perform much better, would involve modifying your `Point` class to implement `IComparable<T>`, like this:

```
class Point : IComparable<Point>
{
    double X, Y;

    public int CompareTo(Point other)
    {
        return (X + Y).CompareTo(other.X + other.Y);
    }
}
```

... which would then allow you to simply do:

```
List<Point> list = ...;
Point maxPoint = list.Max();
```

Comment: OrderByDescending is going to sort your entire list. While that might be fine depending on the size of the list, you need to remember you are turning what should be an O(n) operation into an O(n log n) operation.

Comment: @aquinas: agree with you, I edit my answer to make that more obvious.  I do like my 2nd option better though.

Comment: Well, that also assumes you are the owner of the Point class, which isn't necessarily always the case.

Answer (score 2):

I would add the Microsoft Reactive Team's Interactive Extensions (NuGet "Ix-Main"). They have a bunch of very useful `IEnumerable<T>` extensions.

This is the one you need:

```
Point max = points.MaxBy(p => p.X + p.Y).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxValue = list.Max(m => m.X + m.Y);
var maxPoint = list.Where(p => p.X + p.Y == maxValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

for a highlander..

or

```
var largestPoints = list.Where(p => p.X + p.Y == maxValue);
```

for ties.

Comment: You should move your Max function out of your where clause. As it stands now, the performance would be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing out of the box. You could do:

```
Point theMax = null;
ForEach(x => theMax = (theMax == null || x.X + x.Y > theMax.X + theMax.Y ? x : theMax));
```

But obviously that's not very pretty.

What you really want is write your own extension method, and by write your own, I mean shamelessly steal MoreLinq's (https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs). You can also use: `Install-Package MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy`

Then you can just do: `var theMax = points.MaxBy(x => x.X + x.Y);`

Remember, the beauty/power of Linq is that, at the end of the day, it's all extension methods. Don't forget that you can always write your own to do what you need. Of course, the MoreLinq project usually has what you need. It's a great library.